# Template Engine not Recognizing Package Import from Another Project

Tags: java, scala, maven, playframework-2.0

I have a play 2.3 application that makes use of a lot of existing Java libraries through my local Maven repository. I am able to use these libraries in my scala code just fine except for within my scala templates (*.scala.html files). For some reason the template engine is looking for the Java library object in my play application model package. Here is my  template:

```
@(username: String, userRole: com.data.utils.PlatformRole)

@main() {
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <h3>User Data</h3>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span3">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="text" value="@username"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span3">
                    <label>Role</label>
                    <input type="text" value="@userRole"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
}
```

Here is the error I receive:

```
[error] C:\Server\trunk\app\views\user.scala.html:1: object utils is not a member of package model.com.data
[error] @* user Template File *@
[error] ^
```

For some reason the template engine is looking for the com.data.utils package inside model.com.data. Model is the starting package of my scala project model data where as com.data.utils is where my Java library dependency objects are stored.

I have even tried adding the library packages to the templateImports list inside build.sbt. When I do that, though, the error explained above is shown for all of my template files.

How do I allow my Java library objects inside the templates?

Comment: Is there a `model.com.data` package somewhere in your project? If so, where?

Comment: No, there are packages that start with model, but no model.com.data. The com.data package comes from a different project.